# Zend Framewrok 2 return ViewModel not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I created a Zend Framework 2 admin website based on Zend's Album example.
Everything works in HomeController which is acted as my default controller. However when I created another controller, the view won't loaded. This is my code in indexAction.

```
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel;
use Admin\Model\Map\User;

class UserController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    protected $userTable;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll();

        $viewData = array(
            'users' => $users
        );

        $vm = new ViewModel($viewData);

        var_dump($vm);

        return $vm;
    }

    public function getUserTable()
    {
        if(!$this->userTable)
        {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

            $this->userTable = $sm->get('Admin\Model\Table\UserTable');
        }

        return $this->userTable;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with the table data because it showed up all data when I printed it. However, the result of `var_dump` are always like this:

```
object(Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel)#280 (3) { ["current":protected]=> NULL ["root":protected]=> NULL ["view":protected]=> NULL }
```

But, the view will loaded nicely when I remove the line `return $vm;`, this is useless of course, because I can't pass any data to view if I don't return the ViewModel.

In case it needed, this is my view manager setting in module.config.php:

```
// View
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            // Admin page index
            'admin/home/index'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/home/index.phtml',
            'admin/user/index'        => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/user/index.phtml',
            'admin/ticket/index'      => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/ticket/index.phtml',
            'admin/transaction/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/transaction/index.phtml',
            'admin/customer/index'    => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/customer/index.phtml',
            'admin/payment/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/payment/index.phtml',
            'admin/comment/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/comment/index.phtml',
            'admin/appstat/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/appstat/index.phtml',
            'admin/sysstat/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/sysstat/index.phtml',
            'admin/account/index'     => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/account/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'home'        => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'user'        => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'ticket'      => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'transaction' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'customer'    => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'payment'     => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'comment'     => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'appstat'     => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'sysstat'     => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'account'     => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
```

Please show me where is my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: whats the error message :)

Comment: I've enabled error message by using php ini. There is no single error message appear. Just the correct view phtml won't load.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); - retry - check error_log ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. No error showed on the log. Yes, other error was showed, but there is no error about this ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have used helper ViewModel ( `Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel` ) that gives you this

```
object(Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel)#280 (3) { ["current":protected]=> NULL ["root":protected]=> NULL ["view":protected]=> NULL }
```

Please use model ViewModel (`Zend\View\Model\ViewModel`) instead of helper like below

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
```

Hope this will help you!